# Twitter bootstrap navbar shadow on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm look to do the following 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eIfdn
for the Twitter bootstrap navbar. 
It simply adds a shadow to the navbar upon scrolling. Any advice would be helpful thank you.

```
.navbar {
*position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: none;
*z-index: 2;
margin-bottom: 20px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Thats the css I changed and I added in the js from above.

Here's the JS I used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  if( y > 0 ){
  $("#navbar").css({'display':'block', 'opacity':y/20});
  } else {
  $("#navbar").css({'display':'block', 'opacity':y/20});
  }
 });
})
```

Comment: Are you asking to know how to do something that you have code for?

Comment: Well every time I add the following to the bootstrap navbar it breaks, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "It breaks" is a broad problem.  Can you show us?

Comment: Breaks meaning it doesn't do the desired effect. It only shows the nav bar, and not the shadow effect. I changed the nav bar code to the one posted above in the css file of bootstrap.

Comment: can you show us *your* code?

Comment: looks like it's added by javascript, check in source code view-source:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eIfdn , js is on that page, not included

Comment: Ya, I added in the js I'm using as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is somenthing to get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/pyYfG/

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar" data-spy="affix">
<div class="navbar-inner">
.... standard navbar stuff ...
</div>
</div>
<div id="top-shadow"></div>
.... page content ...
```

**CSS**

```
#top-shadow {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 20px;
width: 100%;
height: 42px;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: none;
}

.navbar.affix{ /* position fixed navbar */
top:0; 
width:100%;
}

/* UPDATE BELOW */
.navbar{    
z-index:1000; /* lift .navbar above #top-shadow */
}
```

The important bits are that I'm using the affix behaviour to lock the navbar inplace, and I'm applying the shadow to a new div just below the navbar. I think this will be easier to manage that trying to add a shadow directly to the navbar itself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I got the effect, but now none of the links are clickable and I have no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: Check out my updated answer now. I added z-index details to the navbar to lift it above the top-shadow.